# How to remove duplicate titles in Views Drupal 6?

Tags: drupal, view

I am using Feeds module with Xpath and it creates duplicates in my database. how to show only one of them? What to set in Views Filters?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Im not 100% sure about this.

Under Basic settings there is a distinct label. Click on it and check the distinct checkbox.

Comment: Thanks, but still not better ;(. This probably removes only the same occurencies of the same node, however I have many nodes with the same title etc, so I need make a filter to allow only one instance according of the title.